# Find a match in a list that contains dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am fairly new to python and I am struggling with finding the answer to my question. I am using an API to get the server credentials and it comes back in a list format.

```
[{u'Username': u'root', u'Message': u'Server credentials retrieved', u'Password': u'P@$$w0rd!', u'Success': True, u'StatusCode': 0]
```

What should I do if I only want to get the password value from it and save it to a file?

Comment: `your_list[0]['Password']` is your password.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is just:

```
the_password = the_list[0]['Password']
file = open('filename.txt', 'w')
file.write(the_password)
file.close()
```